# WSO2 api manager shared application subscription

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have created a secondary User store using LDAP. By default, all users of the secondary store have no permission. Is it a way to assign the suscriber role to all users in one operation or I have to do it manually for each user ?

Thanks

Comment: and also is it possible to share application subscription between user of this secondary store ? I cannot use the Organization field because it is not editable for the ldap user store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since by default WSO2 uses groupId('Organization) of the user to share the Application in the Devpotal as mentioned here in the documentation: [sharing applications](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/consume-api/manage-application/sharing-applications/sharing-applications/)

You can go to the Carbon UI and search for the LDAP users among which you want to share an Application. Next to the User click on the 'User Profile' tab. There you can edit the value next to the  'Organization' column. For this, your secondary user store should be 'ReadWriteLDAPUserStore'. Similarly, edit the value for each user in the secondary user store to the same value to share the Application among them.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, in the ldap user store if you configure LDAP groups there are automatically created as a role and you can apply permissions to a role which will be apply to all users of your LDAP group.

But I didn't find a way to share applications between users of a LDAP group ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better way to achieve it. In the official documentation it is mentioned that it allows the Applications to be shared if we have common roles, in as you said WSO2 treats AD groups as roles.  Lets assume you have two users user1 and user2 in your LDAP store both of which are the part of AD group 'AD_Group'.
So mention the AD group name common to the users among which application needs to be shared : -
[image]
Also change the configuration as following in the deployment.toml file : -

```
[apim.devportal]
enable_application_sharing = true
#application_sharing_type = "default"
application_sharing_claim=http://wso2.org/claims/role
```